# Plotting contour map of interpolated function: unmatching results for different sections of data

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I've determined the value of z = f(x, y) for a grid of points in the plane:

```
import numpy as np

n_theta, n_phi = 20, 30
thetas = np.linspace(0, 1, n_theta) * np.pi
phis = np.linspace(0, 1, n_phi) * (2 * np.pi)

res = f(thetas, phis)
# 'res' is an np.array with res.shape=(600,3), where each row is [x, y, z]
```

Given a `meshgrid` of the `x`'s and `y`'s, I interpolate a function using my previous data for `z`, and plot a contour map of the result:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.meshgrid(res[:,0], res[:,1])
Z = griddata(res[:,0:2], res[:,2], (X, Y), method='cubic')    # Interpolate function.

fig = plt.figure()
contour = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=100)
```

This works fine, and the result (example data linked below) is something like this (which isn't actually the shape I was looking for in my particular simulation):

[image: Result for full data set]

However, when I run the same script with values of `phi` (horizontal axis) only for half of the original interval (or, equivalently, take only this half of my data), I get a contour like this:

[image: Contour for half of horizontal interval]

(For the sake of completeness, if I then do it for the second half of the interval and manually put both figures side by side, the result is like the following, which is more like something I would expect to get from the full data):

[image: Half + second half side by side]

(If needed, this is the [example data to generate the plots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d6myi45zzrwdyh/stackoverflow-example-data.npy?dl=0), followed by a snippet one could use):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Full axis:

res = np.load("stackoverflow-example-data")
X, Y = np.meshgrid(res[:,0], res[:,1])
Z = griddata(res[:,0:2], res[:,2], (X, Y), method='cubic')    # Interpolate function.
fig = plt.figure()
contour = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=100)

# Half axis:

half = np.array([res[i,:] for i in range(len(res)) if res[i,0] <= np.pi])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(res[:,0], res[:,1])
Z = griddata(res[:,0:2], res[:,2], (X, Y), method='cubic')    # Interpolate function.
fig = plt.figure()
contour = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=100)
```

So what am I missing here?

1. Is this the correct procedure to interpolate and plot the contour as I want?
2. Shouldn't I expect to get similar results for the full axis and only half of it? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data are already on a grid. Creating a new grid based on that grid generates something very messy.

Now the array `res` contains 600 x,y,z values. Using `reshape(20, 30)` tells numpy that these 600 entries are in reality 20 rows of 30 columns. The 'purest' form to show the data, would be a `scatter`plot, showing just the data.

With `imshow` the data can be shown as an image. Using `interpolation='nearest'` would 'blow up' each z-value to fill a rectangular pixel. Using `interpolation='bicubic'` would smoothly smear out these pixels.

`contourf` creates contours with equally-valued z. Depending on the data, having many levels (such as 100) would help to get a smooth image, but it wouldn't be valuable compared to just displaying a smoothed image. Having a limited number of levels (e.g. 20) could help to show a general underlying shape.

Here is some code to compare and experiment with the different approaches:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Full axis:

res = np.load("stackoverflow-example-data.npy")
X = res[:, 0].reshape(20, 30)
Y = res[:, 1].reshape(20, 30)
Z = res[:, 2].reshape(20, 30)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 4))
axes[0].scatter(X, Y, c=Z, s=10)
axes[1].imshow(Z, origin='lower', interpolation='bicubic', aspect='auto',
               extent=[X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()])
contour = axes[2].contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=20)
axes[0].set_title('scatter plot')
axes[1].set_title('imshow, bicubic interpolation')
axes[2].set_title('contour plot, 20 levels')

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Experimenting with different [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), can accentuate different properties of the function you are showing. You could also transform the Z-value (such as `np.log(Z)` or `np.exp(Z)`) so different regions get more or less detail.

```py
for ax, cmap in zip(axes, ('viridis', 'inferno_r', 'Purples')):
    ax.imshow(Z, origin='lower', interpolation='bicubic', aspect='auto', cmap=cmap,
               extent=[X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()])
    ax.set_title(cmap)
```

[image: comparing colormaps]

Comment: Just to be sure I got it all, I was using “res”, which is already like a grid, to create a new grid, when what I really should be doing was just reshaping it to an actual grid, as you did. Is that right? I also hadn’t thought of a scatter and didn’t know imshow. This was great help, thank you.

Comment: Indeed, you correctly identified the problem. The "best" approach depends on the true meaning of the data. Additionally, you can experiment with different [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), for example `...., cmap='inferno)` as a parameter to `scatter`, `imshow` or `contourf`. Default the 'viridis' colormap is used. Appending '_r' to a colormap name gives the reverse map.